# Protractor wait for rest call finish

Tags: angular, protractor

I have simple scenario that I want to test if I am able to delete some object. So scenario looks like:

1 Add by rest call some unique object(without using browser, and I dont want to use before each/all because it is specific only for this test)

2 Delete above object in web application

So I wrote simulation of my code:

```
it('test promise', function(done) {
    console.log('start');
    d = protractor.promise.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("rest call");
        d.fulfill('ok');
        done();
    }, 3000);
    console.log('before expect');
    expect(d).toBe('ok'); //code should be stoped here till rest above finish
    console.log('after expect');
    console.log('rest test based on deffer result');
    console.log('change tab... find elements... click to delete...');
});
```

ouput of this code is:

```
start
before expect
after expect
change tab... find elements... click to delete...
rest call
```

So as you can see rest call is run after I will make all webdriver actions...
Some ideas?

Edit:

I've added control flow but it still not works. For code:

```
it('test promise', function(done) {
    console.log('start');
    flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
    var d = protractor.promise.defer();
    var restCall = function _makeRestCall() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("rest call");
            d.fulfill('ok');
        }, 3000);
        return d.promise
    };
    console.log('before expect');
    flow.execute(restCall);
    // expect(d).toBe('ok'); //version 1 not work
    expect(restCall).toBe('ok'); //version 2 not work
    console.log('after expect');
    console.log('rest test based on deffer result');
});
```

output:

```
start
before expect
after expect
rest test based on deffer result
rest call
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you created promise is absolutely correct

The only change needed is to add it into the [Protractor Control Flow](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/). It needs two steps to be added and little refactoring of your code

Step 1: Initiate Protractor Control Flow and then use `flow.execute()` to insert any [async function which returns promise into Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1096)

```
describe('sample test', function(){
    flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();

var restCall = function _makeRestCall() {
                var d = protractor.promise.defer();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log("rest call");
                    d.fulfill('ok');
                }, 3000);
                return d.promise
            }
            flow.execute(restCall)
```

This will place your async call into the Control Flow and the browser command will execute only after the promise is resolved

UPDATE: Added the complete flow of the test case

```
describe('sample test', function(){
    it('test promise', function() {
        browser.get('')
        console.log('start');
        flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
        var d = protractor.promise.defer();
        var restCall = function _makeRestCall() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("rest call");
                d.fulfill('ok');
            }, 3000);
            return d.promise
        };
        console.log('before expect');

        // Can directly add expect here as flow.execute() returns promise 
        expect(flow.execute(restCall)).toBe('ok');

        // All subsequent browser command part of Protractor Control Flow will be executed only after the promise of restCall is resolved

        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(value) {
            console.log('after expect');
            console.log('rest test based on deffer result');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Could u show me example on my code. I edieted first post with sample of code with control flow and it still doesnt works

Comment: @user2771738 .. if you are still trying with `console.log()` statements it will not show results as `console.log()` are not part of Protractor control flow. Have browser related statements to check if the `restCall` is inserted. Also remove the expect, as it will call the restCall twice. I have updated the answer

Comment: Ok so I misunderstood concept of control flow. Now everything works fine.